# Would this question on different forms of compensation for excess solar PV production be a good fit?

Tags: discussion

Over on electronics.se there's a question that might be a better fit over here:

> [Difference between Net metering, Feed-in tariff and power purchase agreement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431978/difference-between-net-metering-feed-in-tariff-and-power-purchase-agreement)

There are just a couple of related questions here, which haven't gotten a lot of action, so I wanted to check first before recommending that the question be migrated here:

- [What do the different rules for photovoltaics feed-in mean?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/what-do-the-different-rules-for-photovoltaics-feed-in-mean)
- [Dominion Energy (Virginia) solar standby charges](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/dominion-energy-virginia-solar-standby-charges)
- [How to set up grid-tied photovoltaics without feed-in?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/how-to-set-up-grid-tied-photovoltaics-without-feed-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if it got closed there, then it could get migrated here: